# ag-grid rendering in Next.js pages

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ag-grid, next.js

Newbie here...need help.  I tried using the sample code for ag-grid on a ReactJS component on NextJS.  I am getting a loading css error (please see further below).

(Before this, I was able to make the code run using 'create-react-app' "https://www.ag-grid.com/react-getting-started/")

Here's the error message:
[appropriate loader needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP6XP.png)

I have searched and tried out related (searched-out) answers like adding this on webpack.config.js:
[webpack config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk7LH.png)

and also tried adding this on package.json:
[package json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9hoM.png)

I may be missing out on how to correctly load css on the Next JS setup.

Here's the code..[taken mostly from the sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcnQ4.png)

Answer (score 1):

In Next.js you configure webpack inside a `next.config.js` file. There should be no `webpack.config.js` (at least to my knowledge).

There's a plugin called [next-css](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-css) which you install with: `npm install --save @zeit/next-css`.

Then, in your `next.config.js` file, write:

```js
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
module.exports = withCSS()
```

The `ag-grid` example worked for me after doing that.